# How to create a conditional that works if an int is contained twice in a list

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

This quite simple game asks the user to guess a random number. The program ends when he guesses.
I wanted to add a simple feature, i wanted notitfy the user when he used twice the same number.
The problem is that the conditional that i wrote is always true, it prints "You already tried that number" every time.

I know how to make the program work, i just don't know what to write. It would be smart to say `if guess` is contained twice `in previous_guess`.

```
    # myNumber.py
# This game uses a home made function


def num():
    import random

    # Think a number
    computer_number = random.randint(1, 100)

    def is_same(target, number):
        if target == number:
            result = "Win"
        elif target > number:
            result = "Low"
        else:
            result = "High"
        return result

    # Start the game
    print("Hello.\nI have thought of a number between 1 and 100:")

    # Collect the user's guess as an integer
    guess = int(input("Can you guess it?"))
    # Use our function
    higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)
    # run the game until the user is correct
    while higher_or_lower != "Win":
        if higher_or_lower == "Low":
            guess = int(input("Sorry you are too low. Try again"))
        else:
            guess = int(input("Sorry you are too high. Try again"))

        higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)
```

This is the part i wanted to add

```
previous_guess = [guess]
if guess in previous_guess:
            print("You already tried with that number")

#previous_guess = []
#previous_guess.append(guess)
#I could also write it like this, same thing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append it within the while loop and rearrange your code accordingly:

```
previous_guesses = list()
# Collect the user's guess as an integer
guess = int(input("Can you guess it?"))
previous_guesses.append(guess)

# Use our function
higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)
# run the game until the user is correct
while higher_or_lower != "Win":
    if higher_or_lower == "Low":
        guess = int(input("Sorry you are too low. Try again"))
    else:
        guess = int(input("Sorry you are too high. Try again"))

    if not guess in previous_guesses:
        previous_guesses.append(guess)
        higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)
    else:
        print("You already tried with that number")
```

Comment: I tried to run it, this is the console output: I have thought of a number between 1 and 100:
Can you guess it?1
Sorry you are too low. Try again1
Sorry you are too low. Try again100
Sorry you are too high. Try again1
You already tried with that number
Sorry you are too low. Try again

Comment: It didn't count the first try

Comment: @serax: Right, changed the answer.